# Binomial newton (a-b)^n(Python)

Tags: python

I need help with the code for the Newton's binomial.I attach the code that outputs the binomial (x + y)^n,and I need to write the code for (x-y)^n.How to write this alternation in the code?

```
def fact(m):
   f = 1
   for i in range(1,m+1):
      f = f*i
   return f
 
def koef(n,k):
   x = fact(n)
   y = fact(k)
   c = fact(n-k)
   return x//(y*c)
 
print("Enter n:")
n = int(input())
k = 0
while k <= n:
   print(koef(n,k),"*x^",n-k,"*y^",k,sep = '', end = '')
   k = k+1
   if k <= n:
      print(" + ",end = '')
```

The binomial that outputs this code:
n = 10

> x^10+10x^9*y+45x^8*y^2+120x^7*y^3+210x^6*y^4+252x^5*y^5+210x^4*y^6+120x^3*y^7+45x^2*y^8+10x*y^9+y^10

The bean I need to display:
n = 10

> x^10-10x^9*y+45x^8*y^2-120x^7*y^3+210x^6*y^4-252x^5*y^5+210x^4*y^6-120x^3*y^7+45x^2*y^8-10x*y^9+y^10

Comment: Don't print + at the end but print (-1)^k. With print('{}'.format((-1)^k))

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to alternate `+` and `-` depending on the parity of `k`. You can do it in a number of ways but one that comes to mind is the following:

```
if k <= n:
    operation = '+-'[k % 2]  # + on even, - on odd
    print(' ' + operation + ' ', end=' ')
```

you may also use format string:

```
if k <= n:
    operation = '+-'[k % 2]  # + on even, - on odd
    print(f' {operation} ', end=' ')
```